# Questions only from my favorite tags

Tags: discussion, support

How can I get the questions from only from my favorite tags in one place? I would like to answer questions what i know, its not a efficient way to run around tags for new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions right here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

There is support for AND OR and NOT in this combination of tags.